# Would bottle flipping in lower gravity be easier?

Tags: gravity, moon

Let's say I'm on the moon and I try to do a bottle flip. (Fill bottle 1/3 with water, flip it, and it lands on its bottom). Would it be easier to perform a bottle flip in lower gravity?

My guess is yes, because you can spin it slower, because it has more time in the air. But I am not a physics person, so that is why I am asking here.

Comment: It's not clear to me what (if anything) would establish a characteristic scale for the problem.  I.e. perhaps the amount of force has no effect on the ease of flipping.  Is there a difference on earth with different bottle weights (assuming they are light enough to throw)?

Comment: What do you mean by "would it be easier"? "Easier" is not a scientific term, it could mean many things, and it is not obvious what you intend it to mean. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @sammygerbil  I took it to mean, easier to achieve the trick. It's a bit impressive, I think, when it's done with two bottles simultaneously, but  after that, maybe not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think the rate of spin, or the time in the "air" :) on the moon, as compared to Earth, would have any different effect?

The timing is important, so like on Earth you need get the spin rate just right, so that lands on it's base. Then think about what happens when it lands and rocks side to side as the water sloshes around inside of it.

Gravity is less, and what you want for it to work better on the moon than Earth is for those oscillations to be damped so it never goes beyond  its equilibrium point when it tips to one side and falls over.

So in the end, it still seems to come down to practice at getting the spin rate just right

The best way to think about it is to  imagine a slow motion version of what happens on Earth.